# Ubuntu 12.04 fstab corrupted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, device, mount

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 in my pc and for some accident my /etc/fstab file became corrupted, i have already checked and no backup was made. The pc has installed Windows as well and I don't really know how to build the file based on the information of the `blkid` command and the `mtab` file.
Although i'm familiar with the syntax of the `fstab` file, I don't know what information has to be inlcuded based on the situation of having a windows partition besides Linux so I has hoping somebody could help me with the construction of the file.

Here's the `blkid` info.

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="BA04384104380345" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Vista" UUID="608085478085249E" TYPE="ntfs"     
/dev/sda5: UUID="ffc7dedc-ce6c-45a9-b233-7ce214682178" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="1347e64b-d51e-4410-ae43-cfdac8959583" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660"
```

And the `mtab` file.

```
/dev/sda5 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Currently, i'm booting from the live CD so I guess one of the devices is the CD media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and looking at my fstab, I think this should work for you (I updated with your UUIDs):

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# main
UUID=ffc7dedc-ce6c-45a9-b233-7ce214682178 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0
# swap
UUID=1347e64b-d51e-4410-ae43-cfdac8959583 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on you `mtab` and `blkid` output, your system has two major linux partitions `/dev/sda5` which is mounted as `/` and `/dev/sda6` which is mounted as `swap`. Rest other partitions are virtual file systems and they will be mounted automatically by the `init` during the time of 
reboot.

Add below lines to your `/etc/fstab` file and reboot the system, it should be safe.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda5   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda6   none    swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

It is not necessary to consider windows partition at this stage if you are not mounting any of the windows partitions.